# Insert into based on a select query with joins issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

based on other table called TableCodes that have 3 records

```
Code
1508
1509
1510
```

And I have this result from my query i a temporal table....

```
CapacityDate    InstallerCode   WorkAreadID FoxtelCodeID    value 
2/8/12          BAW                  7          1508                  3 
3/8/12          BAW                  7          1508                  1
4/8/12          BAW                  7          1509                  1
```

I need to insert in the same table the other records missing based on TableCodes with value = 0

I want this

```
CapacityDate    InstallerCode   WorkAreadID FoxtelCodeID    value 
2/8/12          BAW                  7          1508                  3 
2/8/12          BAW                  7          1509                  0 
2/8/12          BAW                  7          1510                  0 
3/8/12          BAW                  7          1508                  1
3/8/12          BAW                  7          1509                  0
3/8/12          BAW                  7          1510                  0
4/8/12          BAW                  7          1508                  1
4/8/12          BAW                  7          1509                  0
4/8/12          BAW                  7          1510                  0
```

I'm using the following code

```
Insert into #TmpAdjustmentTable (
    CapacityDate, InstallerID, InstallerCode, InstallerName,
    bThisIsAnAdjustment, sStatusOfCapacity, WorkAreadID, WORKAREA,
    CapacityState, FoxtelCodeID, SINTERNALLABELFORCAPACITY,
    SLABELFORCAPACITY, CapacityUnits, Capacity, MaxJobs, CommentsForDay
)
select
     ta.CapacityDate, ta.InstallerID, ta.InstallerCode, ta.InstallerName,
     1, ta.sStatusOfCapacity, ta.WorkAreadID, ta.WORKAREA,
     ta.CapacityState, FoxtelCodes.SYSID, FoxtelCodes.SINTERNALSHORTLABELFORCAPACITY,
     FoxtelCodes.SLABELFORCAPACITY, 0, 0, 0, ta.CommentsForDay
from #TmpAdjustmentTable ta
inner JOIN FoxtelCodes
On FoxtelCodes.SYSID <>  ta.FoxtelCodeID 
and FoxtelCodes.BCOLLECTTHISFORCAPACITY = 1
```

but I got ...

```
CapacityDate    InstallerCode   WorkAreadID FoxtelCodeID    value 
2/8/12          BAW                  7          1508                  3 
2/8/12          BAW                  7          1509                  0 
2/8/12          BAW                  7          1510                  0 
3/8/12          BAW                  7          1508                  1
3/8/12          BAW                  7          1508                  0
3/8/12          BAW                  7          1509                  0
3/8/12          BAW                  7          1509                  0
3/8/12          BAW                  7          1510                  0
3/8/12          BAW                  7          1510                  0
4/8/12          BAW                  7          1508                  1
4/8/12          BAW                  7          1508                  0
4/8/12          BAW                  7          1509                  0
4/8/12          BAW                  7          1509                 0
4/8/12          BAW                  7          1510                  0
4/8/12          BAW                  7          1510                  0
```

Answer (score 0):

hi check the query below to get the output in the requested format.

--Here I tried getting the output without using the while loop but I could not sucees.I will try to get that mean while you can check this and hope it will be useful.

```
Declare @min int,@max int
SELECT @min=MIN(idn),@max=MAX(idn) from Results
SELECT @min,@max
Declare @tbl_out table (CapacityDate datetime,InstallerCode varchar(100),WorkAreadID int,FoxtelCodeID int,value int)
While(@min<=@max)
begin
;With CTE(CapacityDate,InstallerCode,WorkAreadID,FoxtelCodeID,value) AS
(SELECT CapacityDate,InstallerCode,WorkAreadID,FoxtelCodeID,value from Results where idn = @min)

,CTE1(code,value) AS
(SELECT C.code,isnull(T.Value,0) FROM Codes C LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE T on C.code=T.FoxtelCodeID)
insert into @tbl_out
select r.CapacityDate,r.InstallerCode,r.WorkAreadID,c.code,c.value from CTE1 c,CTE r
SET @min+=1
End
select * from @tbl_out
select * from Results
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey This is the latest one without while loop

```
Select CapacityDate,InstallerCode,WorkAreadID,code,0 value from Results join Codes
on FoxtelCodeID<>code
union all
Select CapacityDate,InstallerCode,WorkAreadID,FoxtelCodeID,value from Results 
order by CapacityDate, value desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the distinct combinations of `CapacityDate`, `InstallerCode`, `WorkAreadID` that already are in the temporary table, cross join them with the Codes in `TableCodes`, then filter out the rows for which the temporary table has already got matches with the same date and code. In SQL, it might look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO #Table (
  CapacityDate,
  InstallerCode,
  WorkAreadID,
  FoxtelCodeID,
  value
)
SELECT
  d.CapacityDate,
  d.InstallerCode,
  d.WorkAreadID,
  c.Code,
  0
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    CapacityDate,
    InstallerCode,
    WorkAreadID
  FROM #Table
) d
CROSS JOIN TableCodes c
LEFT JOIN #Table t ON d.CapacityDate = t.CapacityDate AND c.Code = t.FoxtelCodeID
WHERE t.FoxtelCodeID IS NULL
```